# Querying embedded documents in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack, mean.io

I tried to run this query in my nodeJs app

`Book.find({'user._id': '545e2915cd91299447fdb8d7'}).populate('user').exec(function(err, books){...}`

and it is not working(it returns empty list) but I tried to run this query in cmd using mongo and it was working. Can anyone please help me?

here is scheme for book:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    path = require('path');

/**
 * Book Schema
 */
var BookSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String, 
        trim: true, 
        required: 'Title is missing'
    },
    created: { 
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now 
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
 });

mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure where was the problem. Problem was that I created books manually in mongo shell and for some unknown reason it was not working but when I persisted book in app the query with user id was working. I do not understand why(because there should not be any difference when entered in mongo shell and persisted in app) but it works.

Comment: `user._id` is supposed to be an ObjectId, not a string as in your query. That's likely the source of the problem.

Comment: yeah when creating I should use ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011") instead of string - "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"